# Why do I keep receiving badge notifications from my old unused profile?

Tags: bug, notifications, user-accounts, merge-accounts

A moment ago, I noticed I got a gold badge related to [this question](//serverfault.com/questions/601394/launch-firefox-on-remote-server-using-ssh-with-a-command-line-parameter). I clicked on it and I found it is related to [another profile](//serverfault.com/users/223514/begueradj) of mine I did not use for ages as I have no idea which email and password I used for it.

But I am not supposed to see that badge on my [present profile](//serverfault.com/users/270090/begueradj?tab=profile). Is not this a bug?

Note that I asked in the past to merge that profile to my current one but I have not received any answer.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Note that I do not receive any other notifications except the ones of the same nature (badges). If someone comments on one of my posts on the other profile, I won't receive any notification here.

Comment: I'd say that was fairly strong evidence the profiles had been linked, wouldn't you?

Comment: I want to think the same thing but if someome comments for example one of my posts on the other profile, I won't receive any notification.  Also that badge does not appear on my present profile, only on the other @MadHatter

Comment: Fair enough.  I upvoted this question, anyway, as I think it'd be useful to have some light shed on how linked profiles are supposed to work.

Comment: Looks like a corrupted/partial merge, dunno how it happened but a dev should be able to fix it.