# Still receiving badge notifications related to long time unused profiles

Tags: bug, badges, notifications, user-accounts

I think my question is similar to this one: [Why do I keep receiving badge notifications from my old unused profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267878/why-do-i-keep-receiving-notifications-from-my-old-unused-profile) but this time the bug occurred relatively to the [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) website:

[image]

(Silver badge notification from Programmers website that I am not using but linked to an old profile of mine I did not use for ages for the reason I do not remember even the email address I used there)

Comment: So you say for sure [this profile](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/132583/begueradj) is using  different OpenID than this account of yours? Something on that account is funky, it [has no accounts](http://stackexchange.com/users/4311248/begueradj?tab=accounts) - as if they were all deleted manually, but not fully.

Comment: Yes and sure for your question.  The second link you pointed to looks an rather mystery to me :) Thank you for the note @ShadowWizard

Comment: Your Programmers account is linked to your network account, just not correctly so it's not showing up in your list of accounts but is generating the notifications. I'll poke someone.

Comment: Thank you for the note, but I am no longer use Programmers website. The badge notification I got is rather related to an old profile of mine to which I have no access as I do not even remember which email address I used for it @animuson

Comment: I'm aware of that, and it's the profile which is linked to your network account. We can either fix the link or we can just flat-out schedule the account for deletion and it'll go away in about 24 hours.